# How to use different stylesheet for differenct divs on the same page and at the same time?

Tags: php, html, css

i am trying to use different style-sheet files in different divs at the same time. I have tried by using switch cases, but nothing helps,  ***Please one thing to be notable that i have to show both of the divs at the same time***

here is my code which i have tried so far:

```
<?php
    switch ($type_show1):   
    case 'welcome1':
    //default:
?>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    // css to include
                <div class="page-header">
                    <div class="page-title">
                        <h5>Booking Management</h5>
                        <span>Good morning, Admin!</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /page header -->

<?php
break;
endswitch;  
    ?>

<?php
    switch ($type_show2):
    case 'welcome2':
    //default:
?>
                <link href="css/main2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> // Other css to include
                <div class="page-header">
                    <div class="page-title">
                        <h5>Booking Management</h5>
                        <span>Good morning, Admin!</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

<?php
break;
endswitch;  
?>
```

Comment: Seems like a serious misuse of CSS to me.  Why not just define two styles in the CSS with different classes and use PHP to toggle the element to either have the standard or alternate class?

Answer (score 0):

What's the difference in those stylesheets?
Guess you want something like this?
This way the divs are always shown and the stylesheets are only imported on your switch.

```
<?php
    switch ($type_show1):   
    case 'welcome1':
    //default:
?>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    // css to include

<?php
break;
endswitch;  
?>

<?php
    switch ($type_show2):
    case 'welcome2':
    //default:
?>
<link href="css/main2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> // Other css to include
<?php
break;
endswitch;  
?>
<div class="page-header">
    <div class="page-title">
        <h5>Booking Management</h5>
        <span>Good morning, Admin!</span>
    </div>
</div>
                <!-- /page header -->
<div class="page-header">
    <div class="page-title">
        <h5>Booking Management</h5>
        <span>Good morning, Admin!</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you declaring your 2 stylesheets on the head of your html, and giving two different IDs to your divs ?